# How to redirect a Google Form (new version) to a custom URL after clicking Submit

Tags: google-forms

The new version of Google Forms is nice BUT it's missing 1 critical feature which should be easy, but I don't know how to implement it.

When creating a Google Form, once the visitor clicks 'Submit', I want to redirect them to a **custom URL** or custom Thank you page (i.e., http://cnn.com ).

The current functionality of all Google Forms is to show a message that the form has been submitted. I'd like to bypass that and instead send to a Custom URL.

How can I do that?

**NOTE:** I am **NOT** asking about how to display custom message after submitting a Google Form as that is clearly possible in the form settings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect after submitting Google Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51180394/redirect-after-submitting-google-form)