# Redirect to URL after submit of Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Is there a place to get guidance on where to start with getting the Google Apps Script service to redirect a responder clicks Submit on a Google Form?

I have tried variations of doGet(), getUrl(), onSubmit(), and HTMLService scripts with index and without index.

Is there a source of documentation that will show me how to do this correctly?

It's a standalone Google Form that I just need to redirect. I am not opposed to reading and learning (so please save the comments about not providing me with the script). Looking for actual documentation or post that will show how to get the Google Form to successfully post responses to the Google Sheet and redirect the user to a new web page. I have Googled and tried many different variations of the above. None have been successful.

Comment: Not possible. You can provide a link to manually click in the confirmation message.

Comment: Or create your own html form with the web-app using `doGet()`, which  you can redirect as you wish.

Comment: So, GAS will not be able to execute a script on the form submission trigger to redirect users to another webpage unless I script the entire form outline in GAS?

Comment: Yes````````.````````

Comment: Same question, no answers. [How to redirect a Google Form (new version) to a custom URL after clicking Submit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35897859/1595451)

Comment: Thanks you TheMaster and Ruben. I am a new user, but added my upvote to the link there. I have also submitted a feedback form for a new feature request using the links seen in other posts. I reviewed many many posts and there are plenty that say that it is possible, but no matter what I do to the APIs or scripts...nothing changes.